# Pinboard bookmarklet is blocked after upgrade to Firefox 85

Tags: firefox, popup

The [popup](https://pinboard.in/howto/) bookmarklet worked well until updated to Firefox 85. Now it is blocked by Firefox. As I use this bookmarklet to bookmark websites to [Pinbord](https://pinboard.in/), It is not practical to make exceptions for all websites. How can I make this bookmarklet not being blocked?

The code of this bookmarklet is:

```js
javascript:
q=location.href;
if(document.getSelection){
  d=document.getSelection();
}else{
  d='';
};
p=document.title;
void(
  open(
    'https://pinboard.in/add?url='
      + encodeURIComponent(q)
      + '&description='
      + encodeURIComponent(d)
      + '&title='
      + encodeURIComponent(p),
    'Pinboard',
    'toolbar=no,width=700,height=350'
));
```

The screenshot when Firefox blocked the bookmarklet:
[image]

Comment: Not sure this question belongs on Stackoverflow, although I'm very much interested in a solution. For what it's worth, this has been reported as a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1689853

Comment: This will be fixed in Firefox 86. I propose to delete this question.

Comment: I think I will answer it after it is fixed in Firefox 86. Do you think it is better to delete it than answer it and why?

Comment: Yes, I think the question should be deleted after Fx86 has been released. At that point, it doesn't provide any real value anymore, IMHO.

Comment: Until it is fixed: you can press Alt+p to open the popup after it is blocked. For me this is a good work around though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1689853) of Firefox 85 as pointed by @stmoebius. Now it has been fixed by Firefox 86.